# Sending data to computer

Tags: database, networking, web

I'm trying to figure out how I could send information and arrange a simple database on my home computer. I'd want to send the information through my phone while I'm away from home. The information is simple it's to keep track of how much money I spend so I would need to send an amount spent, the date (wouldn't matter as much), and the reason it was spent, then store that somewhere and be read when I get home. Any ideas?

Answer (score -1):

You need to port forward your home router on some port (i.e 80 or 8080). Then you can code a small server program or simply host a HTTP server with some script language extension (i.e PHP) to communicate with your database. Your program can define different service calls to manage different tasks (i.e inserting, deleting, updating entries). Using a minimalist REST framework would reduce time being spent on coding.

Edit:

You phone can use these service calls to manipulate your db via its browser or some client program you write.